# "Streaming" a RunProcess?

Tags: run

**Context.** `RunProcess` allows us to execute a system command, and then read its "StandardOutput", "StandardError", etc. This is great for short-lived commands. But consider a long-running process, such as when we compile a large project. When we do this, we get *lots* of output in our system shell (many which might prompt us to stop the call and go do something else i.e. when we get a compilation warning). But we don't get to see this for a long while when we run `RunProcess` in Wolfram.

**Question.** Is there a way to `RunProcess` in Wolfram such that we get to console output stream live to our Wolfram notebook?

Comment: Have you looked at [`StartProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html)?

Comment: Also check out `ReadString`, which can read to the `EndOfBuffer` (i.e. read what's available _now_ then return) or `EndOfFile` (i.e. read until the process is done). This may be useful.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? People won't be able to help if you don't explain why the comments don't solve the problem. As far as I can tell, the answer is `StartProcess` + `ReadString`. Consider addressing comments before starting bounties.